# SharePoint app cross domain call using javascript - object doesn't support property or method ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, csom, cross-domain

I'm creating an SharePoint app (add-in?). Now I'd like to get data from a list in my host web using CSOM/JavaScript:

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);
var factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appWebUrl);
context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostUrl);
```

Problem is my SP object doesn't support the method ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory (or so the debugger says)? SP.js is loaded and my client context object is initialized. Any ideas what is wrong?

My environment: SharePoint 2013 on-premise

Comment: Without directly answering your question, I've found that you can skip setting the `webRequestExecutorFactory` at all and things still generally work... despite the examples provided on MSDN explicitly using the syntax you highlight.  May be worth a shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dstarkowski got me on track, sp.requestexecutor.js had not been initialized properly. This worked out for me:

```
$(function () {
  $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", execCrossDomainRequest);
});

function execCrossDomainRequest() { 
  var context = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);
  var factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appWebUrl);
  [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn735922.aspx), `SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory` is located in `sp.requestexecutor.js` file. Is it included in your application?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, I have a reference to sp.requestexecutor.js.